# How to convert array of objects into enum like key value pair in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I have an array

```
const a = [
  { name: "read-web-courses" },
  { name: "example" },
  { name: "t_gql" },
  { name: "ddddd" },
];
```

I am trying it to reduce it to the below given output , However I am stuck

**Output**

```
{0:"read-web-courses",1:"example",2:"t_gql",3:"ddddd"}
```

Comment: What got you stuck?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could map the wanted property and assign the pairs to the object.

```js
const
    array = [{ name: "read-web-courses" }, { name: "example" }, { name: "t_gql" }, { name: "ddddd" }],
    result = Object.assign({}, array.map(({ name }) => name));

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

This is accomplished using `Array#reduce`, where you can use the index from the `reduce` callback as the key of the new object:

```js
const a = [ { name: "read-web-courses" }, { name: "example" }, { name: "t_gql" }, { name: "ddddd" }];

const res = a.reduce((r, o, i) => {
  r[i] = o.name;
  return r;
}, {});

console.log(res);
```

Also one more approach using `Object#fromEntries`  and `Array#map`, where  each object is converted to an array of key, value pairs:

```js
const a = [ { name: "read-web-courses" }, { name: "example" }, { name: "t_gql" }, { name: "ddddd" }];

const res = Object.fromEntries(a.map((o, i) => [i, o.name]));
console.log(res)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Array.reduce` like below.

```js
  const a = [
    { name: "read-web-courses" },
    { name: "example" },
    { name: "t_gql" },
    { name: "ddddd" },
  ];
  
  const convert = arr => (
    arr.reduce((total, value, index) => {
      total[index] = value.name;
      return total;
    }, {})
  )

  console.log(convert(a));
```